# What is the way to populate a dropdownlist from a database in asp.net by using classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist from sql server by using classes as shown below. The code breaks down when it comes to bind the data into the dropdown list. It gives an error on giving the dropdownlist the dataValueField and datatTextField.

HTML... a.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="NationalityDropDownList" runat="server"  >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

C#... a.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Classes.Nationality PossibleNationality = new Classes.Nationality();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {              
            DataTable dataTable = PossibleNationality.getNationality();
            NationalityDropDownList.DataSource = dataTable;

            NationalityDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
            NationalityDropDownList.DataTextField = "Nationality";
            NationalityDropDownList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Nationality.cs

```
 public class Nationality
 {
   public DataTable getNationality()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        string  connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InformationConnection"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("spGetAllUsers", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dataTable;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = comm;
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

SQL procedure....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetNationalities] 
AS
BEGIN
    select * from Nationality;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code in your `getNationality`method...

```
comm = new SqlCommand("spGetAllUsers", conn);
```

...should be this instead

```
comm = new SqlCommand("spGetNationalities", conn);
```

Databinding should work if your `Nationality` table has columns ID and Nationality

Answer (score -2):

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = NIPOON; Initial Catalog = CustomerOrders; Integrated Security = true"))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Customer", con);
                    con.Open();

                    dropDownList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
                    dropDownList.DataValueField = "Name";
                    dropDownList.DataBind();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + Ex.Message);
            }

            GetData();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, not just a code dump.